# Center the elements, navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am going to create responsive design with Bootstrap first time, just set up the nav elements.

But here is my problem: the navigation container is not coming center of the page.

Please see 1.jpg this is so far I have. See the 2.jpg that I want.![this is so far I have][1]

Although if I use my own wraper like `.mainContainer` that comes what I want. but wanted to know is there possible to achieve the desired result through the bootstrap css?

I tried several methods, like text-align center etc...
![this I want][2]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <nav>            
            <div class="navbar-inner" >        
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Workshops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>      
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I tried offset span also but didn't get what I want. if I use `.container` class that is good but wanted to do this using `.container-fluid`. Let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Missing the images in your question

Comment: @Bondye as he/she is the first user so can't upload image here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://bootply.com/73827

You can center the menu by using:

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-inner {
    display: inline-block; /* makes element respond to parent's text-align */
}
```